# How to validate a file downloaded from svn - Python, osx

Tags: python, macos, validation, svn, checksum

I download files from SVN, the files are quite big (~300MB)
I use the script many times and in case the file already exists i don't want downloading it again, for that i need to validate that the file i have is the same that is on SVN (connectivity issues kill my script sometimes and the download doesn't finish)

Is there any way validating before downloading? (like get the checksum of the svn file, which i couldn't find how to do)

I'm using this line for the download:

```
    fn,download_exit_code=urllib.urlretrieve(url_path,ver_name)
```

Thanks ahead...

Answer (score 0):

You could check the SVN revision number. Here's some code which works for me:

```
import subprocess
svn_url = ...
version_string = subprocess.check_output("svnversion")
parts = version_string.split(":")
svn_version = int(''.join([s for s in parts[-1] if s.isdigit()]))

repository_info = subprocess.check_output(
        "svn info " + svn_url
        )
for line in repository_info.split("\n"):
    if line.lower().startswith("last changed rev"):
        latest_svn_version = int(''.join([s for s in line if s.isdigit()]))
if svn_version < latest_svn_version:
    # Download new
```

Does require you to use SVN to download your file, though (through an `svn up`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to svn you could checkout the file with svn checkout and then run svn update. svn update will update the file if it has changed and otherwise do nothing.

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir('/path/to/file')
subprocess.check_call('svn update')
```